# Get a Time Zone StandardName (Not Local)

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, timezone

I'll start by saying I'm not that experienced in C# and I'm writing a **Windows Forms Application** that writes to an XML file that PowerShell can later read the elements from at different points during configuration.

I created a ComboBox that enumerates the Time Zone DisplayNames, which works great.

```
ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> systemTimeZones;
systemTimeZones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
cbTimeZone.DataSource = systemTimeZones;
cbTimeZone.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
```

I'm trying to get the StandardName of the selected DisplayName Time Zone in the ComboBox.  I've found TimeZoneInfo.Local.StandardName but that's not what I'm looking for since I'm not concerned with the current system information.  I want to use a SelectedIndexChanged event for the ComboBox to display the StandardName in a label.  It seems there has to be a simple way that I've just missed the past 2 days of reading.

Comment: Wanderlust - You said you were using WPF, but `DataSource` and `BindingContext` are WinForms combobox properties.  They don't exist in WPF.  Which is it?

Comment: Matt: The timezone isn't needed if the transfer is done using UTC.  When answering questions you have to make sure the design of the code is correct as well as the syntax and usage.  It doesn't make sense to fix a coding issue if the application won't work.

Comment: @jdweng - The OP has not *asked* about transferring time values or converting time at all.  You seem to be suggesting that they not create a time zone picker at all, but there is no basis for that, as we don't have any information about how this picker is to be used.  UTC is not a panacea.  There are indeed scenarios where you need to ask the user for their time zone.  Regarding the WPF vs WinForms question, that is indeed important, as one can't answer the question correctly without it.

Comment: Sorry, Matt. This is a **Windows Forms Application**, I updated the original question.  I have something I'm modifying in WPF and posted WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the TimeZoneInfo class e.g.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (var zone in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
        {
            cbTimeZones.Items.Add(zone.DisplayName);
        }
    }

    private void cbTimeZones_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var zone = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().Single(x => x.DisplayName == ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem.ToString());
        lblTimeZone.Text = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(zone.Id).StandardName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Matt.  I'm missing how to get that FindSystemTimeZoneById since, as far as I know, it's the same as the StandardName. I can only seem to get the DisplayName when I use TimeZoneInfo.  I've seen quite a few examples for Console.WriteLine output but I'm not sure how to change that to the form.

Comment: @Wanderlust - Your combobox should *show* the `DisplayName`, and use the `Id` for the associated *value* of the item.

Comment: Thanks, Matt! That works great at getting the StandardName from the ID!  I'm just trying to figure out how to make the ComboBox still show the DisplayName to make it easier to choose from in the list.  

I would think it has to convert the ComboBox (DisplayName) to the ID and then from ID to StandardName, if that's possible.

Comment: Thank YOU, Matt! Works great. I would have never gotten that. I appreciate your help!